# SAS If Else and LAG skips a row

Tags: sas

I was trying to use the following code to do calculate cumulative return ():

```
retain MIDPRICE CUM_RETURN; 
LAG_MIDPRICE = lag(MIDPRICE);
LAG_CUMRETURN = lag(CUM_RETURN);   
return_sec = (MIDPRICE - LAG_MIDPRICE) / LAG_MIDPRICE; 
if first.symbol then CUM_RETURN = 0;
else CUM_RETURN  = return_sec + LAG_CUMRETURN;
```

However, with the if and else statement, the SAS is skipping a row:

```
+--------+----------+------+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------------+
| SYMBOL |   DATE   | time |  CUM_RETURN  |  return_sec  |    RMIN     |  one_M   | MK_RETURN_RATE |
+--------+----------+------+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------------+
| A      | 20130108 |    1 | 0            |              | 0.00023571  | 1.90E-11 | 3.130243764    |
| A      | 20130108 |    2 |              | -0.00117855  | 0.000235988 | 1.90E-11 | 0.000274509    |
| A      | 20130108 |    3 | 0.000471976  | 0.000471976  | 0.000235877 | 1.90E-11 | 6.86083E-05    |
| A      | 20130108 |    4 |              | -0.000471754 | 0.000235988 | 1.90E-11 | 6.86036E-05    |
| A      | 20130108 |    5 | -0.000471976 | -0.000943953 | 0.000236211 | 1.90E-11 | 6.85989E-05    |
| A      | 20130108 |    6 |              | -0.002362112 | 0.000236771 | 1.90E-11 | 0              |
| A      | 20130108 |    7 | 0.000711876  | 0.001183852  | 0.000236491 | 1.90E-11 | -0.000137188   |
| A      | 20130108 |    8 |              | 0.001300698  | 0.000236183 | 1.90E-11 | 0              |
| A      | 20130108 |    9 | 0.000711876  | 0            | 0.000236183 | 1.90E-11 | 0              |
| A      | 20130108 |   10 |              | 0            | 0.000236183 | 1.90E-11 | 0.000137207    |
| A      | 20130108 |   11 | 0.000711876  | 0            | 0.000236183 | 1.90E-11 | 0.000137188    |
| A      | 20130108 |   12 |              | 0.000590458  | 0.000236044 | 1.90E-11 | 6.85848E-05    |
| A      | 20130108 |   13 | 0.000711876  | 0            | 0.000236044 | 1.90E-11 | 0              |
| A      | 20130108 |   14 |              | -0.000118022 | 0.000236072 | 1.90E-11 | -0.0003429     |
| A      | 20130108 |   15 | 0.000711876  | 0            | 0.000236072 | 1.90E-11 | -0.000068604   |
+--------+----------+------+--------------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------------+
```

As you can see, I want CUM_RETURN = return_sec + lag(CUM_RETURN), but it seems that now it is doing CUM_RETURN = return_sec + lag(lag(CUM_RETURN)).

I am aware of the issue that you cannot write lag directly in if and else conditions, that is why i used a LAG variable before the if else condition. But it seems that it is still working in a weird way ...

Besides, if i delete the if statement and do

```
if first.symbol then CUM_RETURN = 0;
CUM_RETURN  = return_sec + LAG_CUMRETURN;
```

The entire column of CUM_RETURN just becomes empty ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `LAG_CUMRETURN`, you have `CUMRETURN` in a `retain`.

(throwing out the other noise)

```
retain cumreturn;
if first.symbol then cumreturn = 0;

cumreturn = sum(cumreturn,return_sec);
```

That should get you what you want.  The `SUM()` function treats a missing value as a 0, so for the first record of each security, `CUMRETURN` will stay 0.

Comment: because you don't need it.  The `retain` statement gives you the lagged value of a new variable.  You should read the documentation on how the lag function works.  It's not as straight forward as you would think.

Comment: but is my way of using lag to calculate the return correct though? return_sec = (MIDPRICE - LAG_MIDPRICE) / LAG_MIDPRICE;

Comment: Yes.  The issue was how you were using LAG() for the cumulative return.  How you calculate the return is fine.

Comment: you might find this library helpful:  https://github.com/FinancialRiskGroup/SASPerformanceAnalytics